# Windows fonts are not recognized on .net 3.5 + windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, windows-xp

I want to set the font of Label by

```
labelTime.Font = new Font("Gotham Rounded Medium", 120);
```

In Win8 this works. On my XP machine not. The font is listed in the font folder. I also reinstalled it but it isn't recognized by winxp+.net 3.5? The font works for example in WordPad.

any ideas?

Comment: Try listing all fonts https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and see if the name is there.

Answer (score -1):

Winforms on win xp doesn't use gdi+. Therefore it can't display otf fonts. Converting those fonts to ttf does enable them on win xp.